# Multiple JQuery click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, click

Let´s say I want to have 10-20 of the following div´s. How can I merge the jQuery code into one bit, so that I don´t have to copy it?

```
<div class="one">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>

<div class="one_new">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>

<div class="two">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>

<div class="two_new">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('.one').click(function() {
    $('.one').css( "display", "none")
    $('.one_new').css( "display", "table");
  });
});

$(function() {
    $('.two').click(function() {
    $('.two').css( "display", "none")
    $('.two_new').css( "display", "table");
  });
});
```

UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/d9x45nyd/12/

Comment: Do they have any common properties? exclude they're all `<div>`?

Comment: Well, 1 and 3 has the same bg_color; 2 and 4 another bg_color; and so on... I just want to change the h2 on click...

Comment: Is the html fixed, or can you change it? You can add a second class to all of the divs, like so: `<div class="one clickme">Click Me!</div><div class="two clickme">Click me too!</div>`

Comment: Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/d9x45nyd/12/ to my question...

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem you want to solve is how to relate elements (divs in your case) so that when one is clicked, a related one is shown and the original element is hidden.

There are a number of ways to do this:

- based on the hierarchy (i.e. find the next div)
- arrays of selectors (hard to maintain with the HTML)
- one handler per item (your original, but that does not scale well)

My personal suggestion, in most situations like this, is to "data-drive" the HTML. That is, the HTML is authored to contain enough meta data to allow decisions to be made by relatively simple code. This puts all the maintenance, e.g. for new elements, together with the elements themselves.

One easy way to data-drive is to use `data-` attributes on the elements e.g. to hold selectors for their related elements.

e.g. this is an explanatory example (so is not the minimum code required):

### HTML:

```
<div class="one" data-target=".one_new">
     <h2>Test one</h2>
</div>
<div class="one_new" style="display:none;">
     <h2>Test one new</h2>
</div>
<div class="two" data-target=".two_new">
     <h2>Test two</h2>
</div>
<div class="two_new" style="display:none;">
     <h2>Test two new</h2>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function () {
    // Only bother to wrap this once - common practice
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the data-target element from the div clicked
    var target = $this.data('target');
    // If it has a target...
    if (target) {
        // use it as a jQuery selector to select the matching div 
        $(target).css('display', 'table');
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mkLqvrrm/2/

This method uses a single *delegated event handler*, attached to a non-changing ancestor element. `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient. It works by listening for the event (i.e. `click`) to bubble up to the ancestor. It *then* applies a jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble chain only. It *then* applies the function to only the matching elements that caused the event.

This method is very efficient to connect and the runtime overhead, at event time, is negligible (as you can't click the mouse fast enough to notice any difference compared to a directly connected event handler).

Comment: @codemaniac: The code can be shortened a little more, but I wanted you to see the principals clearly. If you are happy with this approach, mark as answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code like :

```js
$(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
    var classAttr = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.'+classAttr).css( "display", "none")
    $('.'+classAttr +'_new').css( "display", "table");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>

<div class="one_new"  style="display:none">
    <h2>Test one_new</h2>
</div>

<div class="two">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</div>

<div class="two_new" style="display:none">
    <h2>Test two_new</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. You need to use something all the items have in common so jQuery can find them. The `div` tag is not a good candidate for this in any real life example, since it probably used a lot of other places on the page. The most common case is to use a class name.

Comment: One problem with this method is *maintenance*, as it assumes only one class is present. If a new class is added anywhere, e.g. for styling, it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes a selector as an argument and creates a click handler, like so:

```
function attachClickHandler(selector) {
    $(selector).click(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $(selector + '_new').css('display', 'table');
    });
}

var selectors = ['.one', '.two'];
for(var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    attachClickHandler(selectors[i]);
}
```

There are many other solutions to this problem, but this is the most simple example of factorising the desired jQuery functionality.

Comment: You meant "refactoring", not "factorising", but this solution is more complicated than needed for the simple task of relating elements. Better off data-driving the selection using data- attributes.

Comment: Yes, I do -- thanks! I disagree however that it is more simple to introduce custom data attributes as a solution in this instance.

Comment: Using a single delegated handler, with data to drive selection, is always preferable to using handlers connected in a loop. It is also easier to maintain as the attributes are with the elements and not in an array elsewhere

Comment: I agree. However, I believe that for the purposes of this question (which is what I mean by 'in this instance') it is likely easier for the OP to understand my answer than it is to introduce the concepts you have mentioned. Your theoretical solution is in my opinion beyond the reach of OP's question *How can I merge the jquery code into one bit, so that i don´t have to copy it?.* If you think otherwise, post an answer!

Comment: Now I am back to a real keyboard, I have added my own suggestions with example. You should now see how simple the approach actually is and how easy it is to add new items. IMHO (based on decades of programming) maintenance of the page should be a key concern for everyone up-front :)

Comment: Yep. I have +1'd your answer.